# Prove $\text{rank}(S)\le k-1)$ where $S=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_iu_iu_i^T$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}u_i=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

I've followed this procedure to solve the problem so far:

We know that $$\text{rank}(\alpha_iu_iu_i^T)=1\qquad\forall i=1,2,\cdots,k$$
Since $$\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$$
We can write: $$\text{rank}(S)\le\sum_{i=1}^{k}\underbrace{\text{rank}(\alpha_iu_iu_i^T)}_{1}=k$$
But in the book that I'm reading [page 146 of the book Statistical Pattern recognition edition 2002](https://books.google.com/books?id=ec_QnQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:ISBN0470845147), it's said that the maximum rank would be $k-1$?? (The concept is about [Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) based on Fisher's criterion $J_F(A)=\frac{A^TS_bA}{A^TS_wA}$ for a multi-class classification problem)

- Why should the maximum rank be $k-1$ and not $k$?

---

Maybe I should explain more about $\alpha_i$ and $u_i$ in the concept:

Suppose that we have $n$ samples and $p$ features for each sample in our data and the data can be classifies in $k$ classes:
$$C_1,C_2,\cdots ,C_j ,\cdots , C_k$$
if we assume the number of samples in class $C_j$ in $n_j$, then we can define: 
$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}\qquad\text{Mean of the whole data}$$
$$\bar{x}_j=\frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{x\in C_j}x\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}\qquad\text{Mean of the data in class $C_j$}$$
know we can define:
$$S_b=\sum_{j=1}^{k}n_j(\bar{x}_j-\bar{x})(\bar{x}_j-\bar{x})^T\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$$
I want to prove that 
$$\text{rank}(S_b)\le k-1$$
In the beginning of my question, I've assumed $$u_i=\bar{x}_j-\bar{x}$$ and $$\alpha_i=n_j\qquad\text{number of samples in $j^{\text{th}}$ class}$$
and I've tried to solve the problem.

---

**More information that I've found in my thoughts about the problem:**
Since we have $$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k \bar{x}_j\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^k \bar{x}_j=k\bar{x}$$
we can say that $$\sum_{j=1}^k u_j=\sum_{j=1}^k(\bar{x}_j-\bar{x})=\sum_{j=1}^k\bar{x}_j-\sum_{j=1}^k\bar{x}=k\bar{x}-k\bar{x}=0$$
This means that $u_j$'s are not linearly independent and so the dimension of the subspace, created by these $k$ matrices is less than $k$
This can make me satisfied that $$\text{rank}(S_b)\le k-1$$ **but I'm still seeking a straightforward mathematical proof.**

Comment: Can you post an exact quote or a screenshot of that page of the book?

Comment: It seems to be $k$ since:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\big[0, \ldots, 0, \underbrace{1}_{i}, 0, \ldots, 0\big] = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1
\end{bmatrix} = I_k$$
Perhaps there is an additional condition on $\alpha_i$?

Comment: @littleO here it is [picture 1](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8306548076/1.PNG), [picture 2](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8306548084/2.PNG), [picture 3](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8306548092/3.PNG), [picture 4](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8306548100/4.PNG)

Comment: I looked at the images, thanks. You have an additional condition that the vectors $u_i$ sum to $0$. That seems important.

Comment: @littleO yes you're true. if we consider $u_j=\bar{x}_j-\bar{x}$, then we will have $\sum_{j=1}^k u_j=\sum_{j=1}^k \bar{x}_j-\bar{x}=\sum_{j=1}^k \bar{x}_j-\sum_{j=1}^k\bar{x}=\sum_{j=1}^k \bar{x}_j-k\bar{x}=k\bar{x}-k\bar{x}=0$ because we can write $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\bar{x}_j\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^k\bar{x}_j=k\bar{x}$, which means that $u_i$'s are not linearly idependent and each of them can be written with respect to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see directly that every vector in the range of $S$ belongs to the span of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$.  But the set of vectors $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ is linearly dependent, because the vectors $u_i$ sum to $0$, so the span of $\{u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ has dimension at most $k - 1$.  Hence, the dimension of the range of $S$ is at most $k-1$.

---

Here's the original proof I wrote:

Let $U = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & \cdots & u_k \end{bmatrix}$ and let $D = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \alpha_k \end{bmatrix}$, and notice that
$$
S = \sum_i \alpha_i u_i u_i^T = U D U^T.
$$
Clearly, $\text{rank}(S) \leq \text{rank}(U)$.
The null space of $U$ has dimension at least $1$, because 
$$U \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}  = \sum_i u_i = 0.
$$ By the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of $U$ is at most $k-1$.